# OnCollisionEnter2D bug or missing some code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am totally new to c# scripting and unity... i was trying something on unity and created this code and it's woring fine but some times it's just overlapping "wall" tagged object or even getting out of that circle i am using Edge collider 2D on it and polygon collider 2D on my shooter object and this script is attached to shooter object. check the screen shot for the bug.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collider){
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "wall") {
        StartCoroutine (shooterscale());
        collider.gameObject.GetComponent<bgAnimater> ().animateBg ();
        if (turn) {

            turn = false;
        } 
        else {

            turn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem - what is the code meant to do, what part is the 'shooter' object and what is the desired end result? Also a note that you can condense the part which turns the 'turn' variable to be the opposite of what it is, just make it 'turn = !turn'

Comment: @AidanHorton the code is meant to manage the movement of the shooter(that orange triangle). i want shooter to change the moving direction to opposite whenever it touches the boundary(edge of yellow background) to keep it inside the yellow circle but sometime it's getting stuck in the boundary or just getting out of the background(yellow circle)... as you can see in the snaps, did you get it now?

Comment: I understand now - thanks for clearing that up. A few questions: Have you put a debug.log statement inside the collision method to see if it triggers at the right time? If it does, then is there an error with checking the 'turn' variable? If you could post the code behind changing the direction that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [Rigidbody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html) on the shooter.

Make sure that Collision detection mode is set to ***Continous*** to avoid objects passing through each other.

From Docs:

> When the Collision Detection is set to **Continuous**, GameObjects with
>   Rigidbody 2Ds and Collider 2Ds do not pass through each other during
>   an update. Instead, Unity calculates the first impact point of any of
>   the Collider 2Ds, and moves the GameObject there. Note that this takes
>   more CPU time than Discrete.

and

> When you set the Collision Detection to **Discrete**, GameObjects with
>   Rigidbody 2Ds and Collider 2Ds can overlap or pass through each other
>   during a physics update, if they are moving fast enough. Collision
>   contacts are only generated at the new position.

Hope this helps

Comment: I've changed it to continues but the my problem still remains the same.